# How do i one-hot encode nominal attributes to output as full binary?

Tags: database, unix, scripting, sh, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to run a UNIX script that splits my database into training, test and validation splits. The main issue I'm having is I'm trying to hot-encode my nominal attributes so that when the script is run they are all binary code.

Input:

```
@attribute age numeric
@attribute sex {female,male}
@attribute cp {typ_angina,asympt,non_anginal,atyp_angina}
@attribute trestbps numeric
@attribute chol numeric
@attribute fbs {t,f}
@attribute restecg {left_vent_hyper,normal,st_t_wave_abnormality}
@attribute thalach numeric
@attribute exang {no,yes}
@attribute oldpeak numeric
@attribute slope {up,flat,down}
@attribute ca numeric
@attribute thal {fixed_defect,normal,reversable_defect}
@attribute num {<50,>50_1,>50_2,>50_3,>50_4}
```

This is what I've been attempting:

```
tail -n +19 ~file_location |\
   fgrep -v "%" | shuf | 
   sed -e"s/,/ /g" > temp1.txt
    # The training file
    /bin/echo "SNNS pattern definition file V3.2"  >heart-v-train.pat
    /bin/echo "generated at Mon Apr 25 15:58:23 1994"  >>heart-v-train.pat
    /bin/echo ""  >>heart-v-train.pat
    /bin/echo ""  >>heart-v-train.pat
    /bin/echo "No. of patterns : 364"  >>heart-v-train.pat
    /bin/echo "No. of input units : 25"  >>heart-v-train.pat
    /bin/echo "No. of output units : 2"  >>heart-v-train.pat
           head -$TRAIN temp1.txt |
           sed -e"s/f/1 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/m/0 1/g" |
           
           sed -e"s/typ_angina/1 0 0 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/asympt/0 1 0 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/non_aginal/0 0 1 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/atyp_angina/0 0 0 1/g" |
           
           sed -e"s/t/1 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/f/0 1/g" |
           
           sed -e"s/left_vent_hyper/1 0 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/normal/0 1 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/st_t_wave_abnormality/0 0 1/g" |
           
           sed -e"s/no/1 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/yes/0 1/g" |
           
           sed -e"s/up/1 0 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/flat/0 1 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/down/0 0 1/g" |
           
           sed -e"s/fixed_defect/1 0 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/normal/0 1 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/reversable_defect/0 0 1/g" |
           
           sed -e"s/<50/1 0/g" |
           sed -e"s/>50_1/0 1/g" >>heart-v-train.pat
```

My Output becomes:

```
    0.416667 1 0e0 1ale asy0 1p1 0 0.339623 0.326484 1 0 1 0r0 1al 0.70229 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0r0 1al 1 0
0.208333 1 0e0 1ale 1 0n_anginal 0.415094 0.214612 1 0 1 0r0 1al 0.618321 1 0 0 1 0la1 0 0 1 0r0 1al 1 0
0.75 1 0e0 1ale asy0 1p1 0 0.528302 0.226027 1 0 le1 01 0_ven1
```

Some letters of words are converted but some are not.
My knowledge is that each attributes number of sub-classes dictate how we hot encode, e.g 4 values in attribute will be 0 0 0 1 , 0 0 1 0 etc.

Any help would be great, thankyou.

Comment: Please include a minimal input and expected output. Explain a brief about the encoding is certainly better.

Comment: My inputs are the list with ‘sed’ my expected output should be all binary code. Instead I’m getting mixed binary with some letters still